# How to create shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I run the following i get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in
>   /home3/

```
function list_pages_function( $atts, $content ) {
    return
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
        echo "Define topic and title";
      }
      if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es'){
        echo "Definir el tema y título";
      }
      if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'){
        echo "Definisci il topic ed il titolo";
      }
      if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'){
        echo "Définir le sujet et le titre";
      }
    }
  add_shortcode( 'output_pages', 'list_pages_function' );
```

If I remove `return` it is fine but when I place `<li id="a"><strong>1.</strong>[output_pages]</li>` the output won't be within the `<li>` but it will be right at the top of the content breaking the layout

Comment: Store each string in a variable, then return/echo that var at the end?

Comment: nope, doesn't work, same error

Comment: You can't have `return` like that, it should be a separate statement, typically at the end of a function.

Comment: @alex done, you were right, i answered myself on here, check

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved it:

```
function list_pages_function( $atts, $content ) {
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
    $eng1 = "Define topic and title";
 return   $eng1;
  }
  if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es'){
    $es1 = "Definir el tema y título";
   return $es1;
  }
  if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'){
    $it1 = "Definisci il topic ed il titolo";
  return  $it1;
  }
  if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'){
    $fr1 = "Définir le sujet et le titre";
  return $fr1;
  }
}
add_shortcode( 'output_pages', 'list_pages_function' );
```